# How to decide which UIScrollView to scroll when showing keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

In my iOS app, I have a regular `UIScrollView` covering the whole screen. This contains a `UIView` in the top (with some header images, tools and other stuff), and further down a `UIWebView` populated with some web content (blog entries and comments).

When focusing on one of the text fields of the web view, hence showing the keyboard, the web view scrolls to put the input field above the keyboard. Problem is that the header doesn't move away, and thereby covering the input field.

So my question is; how do I tell the code which scrollview to scroll when showing the keyboard? Seems to fall back to some default behavior, and scroll the `UIWebView` that holds the input fields. I want to scroll the parent `UIScrollView` instead.

I've tried to set the `.scrollEnabled` to NO on the `UIWebView`, but this doesn't change anything. The `UIWebView` shouldn't even have a scroll capability, since I set the height of the `UIWebView` (and also the `.contentSize` of the main `UIScrollView`) to the height of its content, every time the web view is populated.

How can I achieve this? Or do I have to make the scrolling manually?

Answer (score 2):

You should register for keyboard notification, I don't know if it would fix the problem but take a look here:[Apple doc about keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1).
I this way you will be able to scroll the scrollview with the keyboard on screen, but I guess that the webview will respond too, since it's already registered for keyboard notification, maybe you could also rescroll it listening to this kind of notification.

Comment: Yeah, you led me into the right direction. I rescrolled (reset) the web view at scrollviewDidScroll, and then did some calculations and scrolled the scroll view programmatically. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Dont scroll the content of either to move content up. Either do one of 2 things:-

1: put all the content in a container view and use UIView animations to move everything up. This is what i do.

Or

2: Put everything in a seperate scrollview and use `[scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];` to move it up. Though to be honest this is an old approach and i wouldn't recommend it

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Just for information

From the Apple documentation :

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in
>   UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that warning. But since I've turned off the scrolling on the UIWebView it should be fine. At least as far as I can see? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868999/why-shouldnt-a-uiwebview-be-placed-in-a-uiscrollview