# WKWebView Inside UIScrollView: Scrolling Conflict

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiwebview, webkit, wkwebview

## Context

I have a `WKWebView` that I programmatically embed in a `UIView` and this `UIView` is embedded in a `UIScrollView`.

To visualize:

[image: Scene's View Hierarchy]

and here is the simplified version of what I have done:

```
UIScrollView
|
+---- UIView
|    |
|    +-- UIButton
|    |
|    +-- UILabel
|
+---- UIView
     |
     +-- WKWebView
```

I don't want the `WKWebView` to scroll and I have disabled it by injecting the following script on the page.

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }
```

---

## The problem

Currently, The scrolling doesn't work when I tapped inside the `WKWebView`. But once I tapped back inside the `UIView` above, I can scroll again. I've attached a GIF below of what happened. The red section is the `WKWebView` and the green section is the `UIView`.

[image: Scrolling problem]

---

### What I've done

1. I have disabled the scrolling using `scrollEnabled` and it doesn't work since I can still scroll the `WKWebview`.

   ```
   webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
   webView.scrollView.bounces = false
   ```
2. Inject the following javascript once the web page is loaded (Current solution)

   ```
   document.ontouchmove = function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }
   ```
3. Use a static `UITableViewController` for the view, but I still encountered the same problem.

---

#### References:

- [SO - Why Shouldn't A UIWebView Be Placed in a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868999/why-shouldnt-a-uiwebview-be-placed-in-a-uiscrollview)
- [SO - Disable Scroll on a UIWebView allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437911/disable-scroll-on-a-uiwebview-allowed)

Comment: I don't know if you have solved the problem by now, but shouldn't you use `webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO` (instead of `...false`) to disable it? Or is this just the case for UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue. The workaround for me was setting content inset on `ScrollView` like this:

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(FLT_EPSILON, FLT_EPSILON, FLT_EPSILON, FLT_EPSILON);
```

Looks like there is some optimisation in `WKWebview` which prevents parent `scrollView` to receive gestures when it's size fits within `scrollview` size. Setting insets even with the size of `FLT_EPSILON` makes the `WkWebView` pass gestures.

It works only for `WKWebView` inside `UIScrollView`. When there is `UIScrollView` inside other `UIScrollView` this workaround is not needed.